# My Css Background is Not Working

Tags: css

/* I don't know why my code won't show my back ground.  Please help

```
    header {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 15px; {
    header .banner {
    background: url("http://www.hhbeautysupply.com/modules/blockbanne/img/2ff10e96da748ecea3b41289ad8dfb39.jpg") repeat-x  #891C21;} 
}
}
```

Comment: Is this LESS or SCSS? (Those need different processes to turn them into CSS. And the question isn't tagged [less] or [sass].) If you're just treating this as raw CSS, then that's the answer.

Comment: we will need to see your html markup as well

Comment: I just now noticed that you have two `background` properties. So... which one of these do you mean is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element `.banner` needs `height` and `width` rules.

**Further**: Your css is not properly formatted (unless you are using a preprocessor like sass) it should look like this:

```
header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

header .banner {
  background: url("http://www.hhbeautysupply.com/modules/blockbanne/img/2ff10e96da748ecea3b41289ad8dfb39.jpg") repeat-x  #891C21;
  //height and width rules
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/90eju2dq/2/)**

```css
div {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.foo {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat #891C21;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. my mistake was that i nested the header .banner in the header coding. thanks again. just had to reposition the curly braces.